how to get height of showModalBottomshet to align child widget in center in flutter?
How to get bottomsheet height to show widget in center.
while tapping on button, i am showing modalbottomsheet for available records with listview builder.its working fine but if there is no data, i want to show Text('No data available') in center of modal bottom sheet. i have used Center widget but its still showing at top of bottom sheet. here i dont know how to get height of modal bottom sheet.
here is my code
DraggableScrollableSheet(
            initialChildSize: 0.8,
            minChildSize: 0.4,
            maxChildSize: 1,
            builder: (_, controller) => Container(
              decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                  color: MyHelper.isDarkMode(context)?Colors.black:Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                      topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                  )
              ),
        
        
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(MySizes.sm),
                  child: ListView(
                    controller: controller,
                    children: [
  Text('Showing all records'),

                      


     

                    len == 0 ? const Center(
                        child: Text('No Records'),)
                          : Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: MySizes.sm),
                            child: ListView.separated(
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                itemCount: fetchTransactionByDate(
                                        daySummeryModel.dateTime)
                                    .length,
                                separatorBuilder: (_,__)=>SizedBox(),
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  final transaction = fetchTransactionByDate(
                                      daySummeryModel.dateTime)[index];
                                  return RecentTransactionCard(
                                    transactionModel: transaction,
                                  );
                                }),
                          )
                    ],
                  ),
                ))


I would change how you are doing: Here an another way to do:
                 padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child:  0 == 0 ? Column(
                        children: [
                          Align(child: Text('Showing all records'), alignment: Alignment.topLeft,),
                          Expanded(
                            child: const Center(
                              child: Text('No Records'),),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                          :ListView(
                        controller: controller,
                        children: [
                          Text('Showing all records'),
    
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                            child: Container()
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )),
              ),

THe result:

